# Top CPU consuming MySQL processes

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.6

I am trying to find out the Query which is consuming high CPU, but can't do it so.

This command  top -H gives me the high CPU consuming thread PID, but i cannot match them with my processlist output.

Is there a way to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

You can see which queries are slow by enabling the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html) (`SET GLOBAL slow_query_log=1;` and setting a suitable value for the long query time variable to set a threshold for what you consider to be "long". (E.g. maybe `SET GLOBAL long_query_time=3;` - the unit is seconds). However, queries may be slow for other reasons than high CPU utilisation, e.g. due to high I/O utilisation. Still, this can be a starting point for at least identifying poor queries.

The slow log is by default written to a file in the data dir called '${HOSTNAME}-slow.log'. You can then use a tool like [mysqldumpslow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldumpslow.html) to analyse this file, e.g.: `mysqldumpslow -s t /var/lib/mysql/localhost-slow.log`. It will extract each slow query and order them from slowest to least slow. Or you can use [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) to do the same thing

You can then enable query profiling for your session (`SET profiling = 1;`), execute each of the candidate queries you have identified in the slow query log, and do:

```
SHOW PROFILES;
```

This gives you a list of the recent queries and their query IDs. Use this ID to find the CPU utilisation for each query with:

```
SHOW PROFILE CPU FOR QUERY <query id>;
```

This will show the various stages of the query execution, and the duration and CPU utilisation (user and system) for each of them.

Note that this isn't 100% accurate - the [documentation page for SHOW PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) notes that:

> Profiling is only partially functional on some architectures. For
>   values that depend on the getrusage() system call, NULL is returned on
>   systems such as Windows that do not support the call. In addition,
>   profiling is per process and not per thread. This means that activity
>   on threads within the server other than your own may affect the timing
>   information that you see.

Note also that the page says `SHOW PROFILE` is deprecated as of MySQL 5.6.7, and that the performance_schema is meant to replace it; see [Query Profiling Using Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html). However, there doesn't seem to be a way to extract CPU utilisation info from it, so you may just have to use `SHOW PROFILE CPU ...`

Comment: Get the first few entries from the slowlog via `pt-query-digest` or `mysqldumpslow -s t`, show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Good point, @RickJames , I've updated the answer.